# Running dotnetcore Console application in Service Fabric Guest Executable

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric, guest-executable

I am trying to run a dotnetcore Console application in a ServiceFabric GuestExecutable Container. While I was adding this GuestExecutable service to my SF application, I cofigured as follows

1. Code Package Folder -> ..repos\NewDllGuestSF\CoreConsole\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0
2. Program -> CoreConsole.dll
3. Working Folder -> CodePackage

Here, I know I am trying to host this .dll file as my executable for the GuestExecutable service. This is what I am trying to do but could not somehow. When I tried the same with the treditional .NetFramework app and with an .exe executable, I am able to run it successfully on SF cluster. But I need to do is with dotnetcore application and of course with a dll executable.

So far I have tried is - 
I can generate a dll as well as an exe while building my dotnetcore console application and use the generated .exe file in GuestExecutable. But here, I have to configure my console app to target multiple Frameworks as "netcoreapp2.0;net461", that is something I can not do for some reasons.

When I run my dotnetcore Console app with a dll executable in SF cluster, I faced the following error 
[image]

Here if we see, the GuestExecutable service remains in healthy state but the application doesn't.

Can anyone please help me out on this, all I want to do is to host a .dll file as entry point in a GuestExecutable SF service.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you need to configure `CodePackage` in `ServiceManifest.xml` to run your `.dll` using external executable.

Here is the example how this could be done (please pay attention to **IsExternalExecutable="true"** attribute):

```
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost IsExternalExecutable="true">
        <!-- We are using dotnet cli to launch our Service.dll -->
        <Program>dotnet</Program>
        <Arguments>Service.dll</Arguments>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>
```

Hope it helps.